# What is HashCollision in java? How to get recovery from this? How to get the element in the second bucket because of collision?

Tags: java

```
public void hashcollision(){

Map m=new HashMap();

m.put(1,2);

m.put(1,3);


system.out.println(m.get(1));

}
```

o/p will be 3 , How to get access to 2.

Comment: That's not a hash collision, that's a key collision.  You'll have to use a multi-map (either write your own, or use Guava's `Multimap`).

Answer (score 3):

You need to start by working out what exactly you're wanting to achieve, and whether a `HashMap` is the right tool for the job.

A `HashMap` is a type of `Map`, and the point of a `Map` is to allow you to assign a *value* to a *key*. Think of it as a row of boxes. Each box has a label on it (that's the *key*) and something inside it (that's the *value*).

When you put something into the `Map`, you specify a key and a value:

```
map.put(1,2);
```

This means: find the box labelled `1`, and throw away whatever's inside it, and replace its contents with `2`. If there's no box labelled `1`, then label a new box `1`, and put `2` inside it.

The point is that because this *throws away* whatever was already in that box, your code does this:

```
map.put(1,2); //first time, so label a new box with 1, and put 2 inside it
map.put(1,3); //already a box labelled 1, so throw its contents away and put 3 inside
```

The `2` is no longer stored at all. It can't be retrieved because it's not there.

If you're trying to get out a value you've overwritten, what that suggests to me is that you didn't really want a `HashMap` in the first place, and you'd have been better off with something that allows you to store multiple values for a given key. There are things that do that, but they're not so common as a generic `Map`. It might be that you just need to rethink your code and what you're trying to do.

But forget about hash collisions: they're something that's internal to `HashMap`, and they get sorted out for you by the `HashMap` so that you don't really have to worry about them. They're nothing to do with what's going on here.

Comment: yes you're right, but OP thinks it is what' happening, so giving an explanation to what it actualy is would be helpfull. I've removen my answer since it was really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The previous value associated with the key is returned by the `put` call.  See:  [The Documentation for HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)%20The%20Documentation%20for%20HashMap)

Thus, if you want the old one:

```
public void hashCollision() {
    Map m = new HashMap();
    m.put(1,2);
    int oldVal = (int)m.put(1,3);
}
```

Note that you should check that for `null` which I'm not doing here to save space and time.  If the key was not previously in use, you'll get `null` back (which won't cast to an `int` like this).  Also, use the generics.  That's why they're there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get access to to '2' because in Java, the first value associated with a given key is over-written if you insert a second value associated with the same key. This technically isn't a hash collision. A hash collision occurs when DIFFERENT keys hash to the same bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ConcurrentHashMap and use putIfAbsent which will put into map if and only if its not present so in your case output will be 2. See here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29

Or try to save value when doing put to get previous value i.e.

```
 int previousValue = map.put(1, 3);
 System.out.println(previousValue);
```

See here for details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29

Answer (score 0):

Use a multimap:

```
final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

public void addToMap(final Integer key, final Integer value) {
    if (myMap.get(key) == null) {
        myMap.put(key, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    myMap.get(key).add(value);
}

public List<Integer> getFromMap(final Integer key) {
    return myMap.get(key);
}

public Integer getFirstElementFromMap(final Integer key) {
    return myMap.get(key).get(0); 
}
```

If you don't want to make your own implementation of a multi-map, you can use the one from `commons-collections` or `google guava` (better):

```
import com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
//...
final Multimap<Integer, Integer> myMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();

myMap.put(1, 2);
myMap.put(1, 3);

System.out.println(myMap.get(1));

//Prints [2, 3]
```

Comment: It's possible that's what OP wants to happen, but I suspect the confusion goes deeper, and that what's really needed is not a multimap but a fundamental rethink...